# bootstrap-datepicker no imprime en target.value al seleccionar

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

Estoy empezando a desarrollar en React.js y me encontré con un problema al implementar `bootstrap-datepicker`.

Al seleccionar una fecha cualquiera no me devuelve el `target.value`. Probé con `type="date"`, utilizando el calendario de HTML5 por defecto y sí funciona, pero con `bootstrap-datepicker` no. En cambio, si lo escribo a mano si funciona, pero al seleccionar no.

```
<script>
      $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
          format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
          autoclose: true,
          todayHighlight: true,
          startDate: "-2y",
          endDate: "+1m"
        });
      });
</script>

      handleInput(e) {
        const { value, name } = e.target;
        this.setState({
          [name]: value
        })
        console.log(e.target.value, e.target.name);
      }

      <div className="form-group">
        <label>DATE PURCHASE</label>
        <input type="text" name="date" className="form-control form-control-sm datepicker" onChange={this.handleInput}/>
      </div>
```

Comment: Si usas react, deberías usar el componente reactivo de bootstrap-datepicker, no la librería. Busca react-bootstrap-datepicker o algo por el estilo y usa eso.

Comment: Si, el tema es que ese bootstrap de React estéticamente no es lo que busco. ¿Habrá forma de adaptar el que menciono? Porque con el date de html5 funciona sin problemas.

Comment: No se a que librerías te refieres (cual es la que te gusta estéticamente y cual no), pero sea cual sea la librería que uses que modifique el DOM, de preferencia deberías usar su versión compatible con react. Por ejemplo eso que haces dentro de `<script>` en general es una práctica desaconsejable si usas react. Y si, eventualmente [podrías](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html) integrar una librería a que modifique el DOM, pero si recién te encuentras en una etapa de aprendizaje, te sugeriría que te atengas a seguir las pautas dictadas para el desarrollo en react.